# Add extra Fn key combinations, for example Fn+4 = Home

Tags: laptop, autohotkey, fn-key, button-remapping, sharpkeys

I play SC2 on my laptop, and therefore I have mapped the normal arrow keys to other buttons. To counteract this, I've mapped the numbers 8 4 5 and 6 on my numpad to arrows. Problem is, the original arrow buttons come with Fn key combinations to give Home, End, PgUp and PgDown. I am wondering if it would be possible to have Fn combine with 4 5 6 8 to give the same Home etc.. commands.

Couldn't find anything over this on the interwebz. Thanks :-).

My laptop is Lenovo 15ARE05 and I'm on win10. I'm slightly familiar with AutoHotkey.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it with AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> key isn't handled in software. The BIOS maps <kbd>Fn</kbd> combinations to dedicated keys rather than send them as two keystrokes. The software doesn't know that <kbd>Fn</kbd> key exists.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I solved my problem by using ctrl+arrow=home instead.